# How to have tags that are within quotes ignored? HTML, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im am trying to use innerHTML to make a paragraph display.

```
innerHTML="<html><head></head><body></body></html>";
```

But I am of course getting errors because it is trying to process the tags. How can I get the browser to ignore these tags since theyre in quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
innerHTML="<html><head></head><body></body></html>".replace(/</g,'&lt;');
```

in words: replacing all `<` with `&lt;` will trigger the browser to render `&lt;` as string  `<` but it [the browser] won't try to render the html-string as html. You could also replace all `>` with `&gt;` ofcourse.

Alternatively you can use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, which will escape the string directly:

```
[yourElement].textContent = '<html><head></head><body></body></html>';
```

Comment: what about &gt? Right, I thought this was an idea. +1 for smart trick. Hey downvoter, change your vote to opposite, it's a smart answer!

Answer (score -1):

You should do escape HTML in this case.

How about a common function:

```
function escape(s) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
    s = el.innerHTML;
    return s;
}
```

Usage:

```
innerHTML = escape("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
```

I think using a browser built-in behavior to escape HTML is better than trying to replace all special characters.

Comment: That's *very* expensive way of doing HTML/XML escapement of strings.

Comment: You need to escape many HTML entities as well as two bracers. I think it is short and simple way to escape all HTML characters.

Comment: @c-smile: I did some research and found the replace way the most expensive. You can look at the test here: http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/35

Comment: You just need to replace `<` as this is the character that triggers markup parsing. Your function is about 10 times slower than regexp variant, check this: http://jsperf.com/html-escapement